# Method for connecting Unused comparator pins

Tags: comparator

I have a dual comparator and one of the comparators is not being used. I know with an op amp you're not supposed to connect the inputs directly to ground. The way I do it with op amps is with a voltage divider for half the rail and then put that into the non inverting input and then make it a voltage follower.
But I'm not sure what the correct way to do it with a comparator is.

The way I have the comparator circuit now is both inputs for the comparator are connected to GND and the output is unconnected.

Comment: Why don't you want to tie + to gnd and - to Vdd?

Comment: That would make sense since it would be a logic low. I'm just not sure what is the standard way of doing it is.

Comment: Well, that is. Or look in the datasheet for specific recommendations.